# Qué elementos pueden recibir foco en html?

Tags: html5

Entiendo que todos los elementos de formulario pueden recibir foco (igual me equivoco), pero me gustaría saber, además de esos, qué elementos html pueden recibir foco. Es decir, un `div`, un `p` o un `a` pueden recibir foco?

Gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueden recibir foco los elementos del `form` como `input`, `select`, `textarea`, etc; `a` y cualquier elemento con la propiedad `tabindex`, esto puede ser un `div` o un `p`